# How to implement pop for a stack as an array program?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

Hi I am having trouble implementing a simple pop function for a stack as an array program. The code is below and I am not sure how to fix it.

I am not sure about all the possible cases, so if you could just advise me then I would greatly appreciate!

```
#include "Exception.h"

template <typename Type>
class Drop_off_stack_as_array {
    private:
        int itop;
        int ibottom;
        int entry_count;
        int array_capacity;
        Type *array;

    public:
        Drop_off_stack_as_array( int = 10 );
        Drop_off_stack_as_array( Drop_off_stack_as_array const & );
        ~Drop_off_stack_as_array();

        int size() const;
        bool empty() const;
        Type top() const;
        bool full() const; 

        void swap( Drop_off_stack_as_array & );
        Drop_off_stack_as_array &operator = ( Drop_off_stack_as_array );
        void push( Type const & );
        Type pop();
        void clear();



    // Friends

    template <typename T>
    friend std::ostream &operator << ( std::ostream &, Drop_off_stack_as_array<T> const & );
};

template <typename Type>
Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::Drop_off_stack_as_array( int n ):
    itop(0),
    ibottom(0),
    entry_count(0),
    array_capacity(n),
    array(new Type[array_capacity]){
        //empty constructor
    }

template <typename Type>
Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::Drop_off_stack_as_array( Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type> const &stack ):
itop( stack.itop ),
ibottom( stack.ibottom ),
entry_count( stack.entry_count ),
array_capacity( array_capacity ),
array( new Type[array_capacity] ) {
    // The above initializations copy the values of the appropriate
    // member variables and allocate memory for the data structure; 
    // however, you must still copy the stored objects.


    for(int i = 0; i<array_capacity; i++){
        array[i] = stack.array[i];
    }
}

template <typename Type>
Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::~Drop_off_stack_as_array() {

    delete[] array;
}

template <typename Type>
int Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::size() const {

    return entry_count;
}

template <typename Type>
bool Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::full() const {
    return (entry_count == array_capacity);
}

template <typename Type>
bool Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::empty() const {

    return (entry_count == 0);
}

template <typename  Type>
Type Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::top() const {
    if(empty()){
        throw underflow();
    }
    return array[itop];
}

template <typename Type>
void Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::swap( Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type> &stack ) {
    std::swap( itop, stack.itop );
    std::swap( ibottom, stack.ibottom );
    std::swap( entry_count, stack.entry_count );
    std::swap( array_capacity, stack.array_capacity );
    std::swap( array, stack.array );
}

template <typename Type>
Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type> &Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::operator = ( Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type> rhs ) {
    swap( rhs );

    return *this;
} 



template <typename Type>
void Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::push( Type const &obj ) {
    if(full()){
        array[ibottom] = 0;
        itop = ibottom;
        ++ibottom;
    }
    else{
        array[itop+1] = obj;
        ++itop;
        ++entry_count;
    }
}

template <typename Type>
Type Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::pop() {

    if(empty()){
        throw underflow();
    }

    array[itop] = 0;
    --itop;
    --entry_count;

}

template <typename Type>
void Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::clear() {
    delete [] array;
    array = new Type(array_capacity);
}
```

Comment: Homework?  What's going wrong exactly?

Comment: IMHO, that's a pretty over-the-top class name. I'd say unless you're allowing the user to access the stack like an array, which would then not be a stack, then don't put that in your class name. The user is using a stack, so call it a stack. If you choose to implement it with an array or list is not important to the user as long as it provides the functionality with acceptable efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
template <typename Type>
Type Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::pop() {

    if(empty()){
        throw underflow();
    }

    Type result = array[itop]; // Safe a copy of the top element
    array[itop] = 0;
    --itop;
    --entry_count;
    return result; // return it (your return type is not void,
                   // so you need a return statment which returns a value
}
```

What is strange in your code (and not just in this place) is the `= 0` and what you are doing with the `itop` and `ibottom` counters/indices/...? But I guess that is another question waiting, your immediate problem is hopefully solved with the above.

(And next time at least include the error message/warning you get in the question, thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

When you write template stack for class T, the class T can be an object and not primitive.
Also, you should not assume that class T has empty constructor, since it is enough for you copy constructor only.

Also, after element popped from stack, you have to release resources. In order to do so, you call destructor.

Please see the example implemented this: 
code:

```
#include <new>
template<typename T> 
class stack {
private:
    int itop;  // points to first free
    int size;  // maximal capacity
    T * array; // memory for data

public:
    stack(int n) : itop(0), size(n) {       
        array = (T *)(new char [sizeof(T) * n]);
    }

    ~stack() {
        delete [] (char *)array;
    }

    void push(const T &obj) {
        if (itop < size) {
            new (&array [ itop ++ ]) T(obj);
        } else {
            // error, stack is full
        }
    }

    void pop() {
        if (itop > 0) {
            array[-- itop] . ~ T();             
        } else {
            // error, stack is empty
        }
    }

    const T &top () {
        if (itop > 0) {
            return array[( itop - 1)];              
        } else {
            // error, stack is empty
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you understand what you have written here?

Comment: sorry, word 'delete' was redundant. I removed it. 
Any case, if you use array as a stack, you have manually call constructor and and destructor. namely: 

push: new (array [++ itop]) T (obj); // placement new
pop:  array [-- itop] . ~ T(); // manual call to destructor.